# Unable to update index with mapping in Elasticsearch 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) resource to update the mapping in an existing index but it is given an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "mapper [NAME] cannot be changed from type [text] to [keyword]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "mapper [NAME] cannot be changed from type [text] to [keyword]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Below is the request I am hitting:

```
curl -X PUT \
  http://localhost:9200/company/_mapping \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: a8384316-7374-069c-05e5-5be4e0a8f6d8' \
  -d '{
"dynamic": "strict",
  "properties": {
    "NAME": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "DOJ": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}'
```

I know I can re-create an index with the new mapping but why can't I update the existing one?

Comment: you cant update mapping of a field because you will have type mismatch. for example you cannot index string and integer in a field and assume that elasticsearch must handle it.

Comment: @hamidbayat so what should I do? re-create index?

Comment: yes. re-create index and reindex your data.

Answer (score 1):

The comments in this thread are correct in that changing a `text` field to a `keyword` field would be considered a mapping breaking change (and raise the "cannot be changed from [type] to [type]" exception).

#### You can, however, extend the original `text` mapping to become a [multi-field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) containing a `keyword`:

```sh
curl -X PUT \
  http://localhost:9200/company/_mapping \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "dynamic": "strict",
  "properties": {
    "NAME": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {              <---
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "DOJ": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}'
```

Once this adjustment is through, you can easily pick up this new property through a blank [Update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#picking-up-a-new-property) call:

```sh
curl -X PUT \
  http://localhost:9200/company/_update_by_query \
  -H 'content-type: application/json'
```

Finally, you can target the `NAME.keyword` in your queries. The good thing is, you'll have retained the original `text` too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the mapping of an existing field, you need to create a new index with the correct mapping then reindex your data

> Except for supported mapping parameters, you can’t change the mapping or field type of an existing field. Changing an existing field could invalidate data that’s already indexed.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the NAME? it happen to me because NAME included a point (e.g. "histological.group"